# mimic a image frame

Tags: plotting

When I read a paper, I found a image just like following:

[image]

I don't care about the real curve functions, I only want drawing like it. So I try to coding:

```
g1 = RegionPlot[y > 3 x^2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> LightBlue, BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Orange]];
g2 = RegionPlot[y > 2 x^2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> LightYellow, BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed], FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 16]];
Show[g2, g1]
```

My questions are: 1. How to drawing the black frame like the first image?
2. `Mesh` option will achieve this grids effect?
3. `Mesh->All` will affect the `BoundaryStyle` option?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
g1 = RegionPlot[y > 3 x^2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[EdgeForm[LightGray], LightBlue], 
   BoundaryStyle -> Orange];

g2 = RegionPlot[y > 2 x^2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[EdgeForm[LightGray], LightYellow], 
   BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed], 
   FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 16]];

g3 = RegionPlot[True, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> None, 
   BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black]];

Show[g2, g1, g3]
```

[image]

You can use a single `RegionPlot` to get the same picture:

```
RegionPlot[{y > 2 x^2, y > 3 x^2, True}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1},
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 16],
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[EdgeForm[LightGray], LightYellow], 
   Directive[EdgeForm[LightGray], LightBlue], None}, 
 BoundaryStyle -> {2 -> Directive[Orange], 
   1 -> Directive[Red, Dashed], 3 -> Directive[Black, Thick]}]
```

> same picture

Alternatively, you can add the black rectangle using `Epilog`:

```
RegionPlot[{y > 2 x^2, y > 3 x^2}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1},
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 16],
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[EdgeForm[LightGray], LightYellow], 
   Directive[EdgeForm[LightGray], LightBlue]}, 
 BoundaryStyle -> {2 -> Directive[Orange], 1 -> Directive[Red, Dashed]}, 
 Epilog -> {EdgeForm[{Black, Thick}], FaceForm[], Rectangle[]}]
```

> same picture

Comment: Thanks, the  results are very similar.

Comment: @zongxian notice the meshing is higher around only the overlapping portions, maybe that will help you. This is awesome publication level graphics @kglr!!